# How to use min() together with other column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, sql-server-azure

I am building an application consisting of an SQL backend and several microservices that communicate with this backend. I am trying to get as little data as possible from the database over the wire so I am trying to fetch the exact records so I don't have to start looping in the application logic.

So this is the source table :

| OrderID | Topic | hierarchyLevel | Responsible Person | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 0 | Jason | Open |
| 1234 | A | 0 | Carol | Open |
| 1234 | A | 1 | Jeff | Open |
| 1234 | A | 2 | Alina | Open |
| 1234 | A | 3 | Eileen | Open |
| 1234 | B | 0 | John | Closed |
| 1234 | B | 1 | Danny | Open |
| 1234 | B | 1 | Celine | Open |
| 1234 | B | 2 | Corry | Open |
| 1234 | B | 3 | Logan | Open |
| 1234 | C | 0 | Jason | Closed |
| 1234 | C | 1 | Annisa | Open |
| 1234 | C | 2 | Cedric | Open |
| 1234 | D | 0 | Peter | Closed |
| 1234 | D | 1 | Joanna | Closed |
| 1234 | D | 2 | Freeke | Open |
| 1234 | E | 0 | Carol | Closed |
| 1234 | E | 1 | Cynthia | Closed |
| 1234 | E | 2 | Deidra | Open |

Based on the "orderID" as input parameter for the query , I should get the for every topic the next persons in line , so with the lowest HierarchyLevel number for that topic, that has status "Open". So every topic can return multiple times as long as the returned records have the lowest possible value in "HierarchyLevel" and the status is "Open".

So I would expect this as output for the stored procedure :

| OrderID | Topic | hierarchyLevel | Responsible Person | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 0 | Jason | Open |
| 1234 | A | 0 | Carol | Open |
| 1234 | B | 1 | Danny | Open |
| 1234 | B | 1 | Celine | Open |
| 1234 | C | 1 | Annisa | Open |
| 1234 | D | 2 | Freeke | Open |
| 1234 | E | 2 | Deidra | Open |

I tried to work with min() but with no luck:

Some things I tried :

```sql
select * from mytable as a
inner join (
   select Topic, min(HierarchyLevel) as min_value
   from mytable 
   group by Topic
)  t on t.Topic = a.Topic and a.HierarchyLevel = min_value and a.OrderID = @OrderID and Status = 'Open'



select * from mytable as a
inner join (
   select Topic, Status ,min(HierarchyLevel) as min_value 
   from mytable 
    group by Topic , Status HAVING Status = 'Open' 
)  t on t.Topic = a.Topic and a.HierarchyLevel = min_value and a.OrderID = @OrderID and a.Status = 'Open'
```

None with the desired result. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your SQL Implementation (SQL Server, MySQL, ...)?

Comment: MSSQL running on Azure

Comment: Is `t.RuleName` supposed to be `t.Topic`?

Comment: Yes my apologies, t.RuleName is indeed t.Topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One straight-forward solution is to use a correlated aggregate using *exists*:

```
select * 
from t
where exists (
    select * from t t2
    where t2.OrderId = t.OrderId 
        and t2.Topic = t.Topic 
        and t2.Status = 'Open'
    group by t2.OrdeRId, t2.Topic
    having Min(t2.hierarchyLevel) = t.hierarchyLevel
);
```

Demo [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eea86865a5ea434bbb75ab6cc7d3c8cd)

Result:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to add the predicate `t.status = 'Open' ` at the outer level. Example `insert into t select 1234 , 'E', 1, 'Cynthia','Open'` in your fiddle

Comment: Yes that would indeed be required in this case - the OP will know if that's possible, it doesn't make much sense if the same row can be both open and closed however.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup RANK() OVER (...). I guess something like:

```
SELECT OrderID, Topic, hierarchyLevel, Responsible_Person, Status
FROM (
    SELECT OrderID, Topic, hierarchyLevel, Responsible_Person, Status
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID, Topic
                        ORDER BY hierarchyLevel) AS rnk
    FROM t
    WHERE Status = 'Open' 
) AS T 
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check if all the records with open status `intersect` with said records also having the lowest heirarchy_level per order_id and topic

```
select order_id, topic, heirarchy_level, responsible_person, status
from t
where status='Open'
intersect
select order_id, topic, min(heirarchy_level) over (partition by order_id, topic), responsible_person, status
from t
where status='Open'
```